# how to sign a apk with platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem and signapk.jar and unsigned apk?

Tags: java, android

how to sign a apk with platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem and signapk.jar and unsigned apk ?
Please help.

I am trying to install it with command

```
java -jar SignApk.jar android_keys/platform.x509.pem android_keys/platform.pk8 
application.apk Application_signed.apk
```

but i am getting error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path"

Comment: `SignApk.jar` is not a standard Android SDK tool. Why do you use it instead of `apksigner.jar` from Android SDK? In case of external tools please always provide a link to the used tool, to make it clear which one you are using.

Comment: where can i find apksigner.jar

Comment: It is part of every recent `build-tools` package version in Android SDK.